# deploying create-react-app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, create-react-app

I am trying to deploy create-react-app to elastic beanstalk. My deployment is constantly timing out with

```
ERROR: TimeoutError - The EB CLI timed out after 10 minute(s). The operation might still be running. To keep viewing events, run 'eb events -f'. To set timeout duration, use '--timeout MINUTES'.
```

I have tried a bunch of different things to get this working. This is my `config.yml` file

```
 branch-defaults:
  dev:
    environment: uu-pilot
    group_suffix: null
environment-defaults:
  uu-pilot:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: uu-pilot
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: null
  default_platform: Node.js
  default_region: ca-central-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```

my `nodecommand.config` inside `.ebextensions` folder:

```
option_settings:
aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs:
NodeCommand: "npm start"
```

^^ I have also tried changing the the node command to `react-scripts build` and `react-scripts start`

all dependencies are under `dependencies` and not `devDependencies` in package.json, and here are my scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "react-scripts build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "start:prod": "react-scripts start"
  }
```

I am getting no particular error message, and am unable to review the exact logs as that operation times out too. I've also added this in case it was just a timeout thing:

```
option_settings:
- namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command
  option_name: Timeout
  value: 1800
```

lastly, I deployed a basic node app to see if that would work and it did, so the problem is with the way the create-react-app node server is serving the build folder.

Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: May i ask you why you are trying this? Why not easily `build` your react app and "deploy" it to S3 and serve it as a static website?

Comment: I have been told to do it this way, is there anything I can do?

Comment: Sorry but this doesnt make sense at all... Please follow the way a described earlier: "build your react app and "deploy" it to S3 and serve it as a static website"

Comment: Yea doing that works ... via an s3 bucket

Comment: The server should only be used while development... A small quote out of the GitHub README: "When you’re ready to deploy to production, create a minified bundle with npm run build"

Comment: So are you saying that there are no advantages to deploying this via elastic beanstalk?

Comment: This was happening to us too. For some reason, it suddenly started working when I upgraded the instance from a t1.micro to a t2.medium. No idea why that worked. Guess Amazon just wanted money.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `eb deploy ... --timeout <minutes>`, where `<minutes>` needs to be the amount of time that you think your application legitimately may take up to be deployed.

It can also be thought of as the number of minutes that the EBCLI must wait for AWS to respond with a success/failure message so that it can stop polling and exit. Until then, the EBCLI will periodically poll AWS. When the EBCLI times out, like it did in your case, it does not translate to a failure in AWS; your operation might still be processing and, as the error message indicates, `eb events -f` will show its progress.

The timeout in the `.ebextensions` config file actually refers to the maximum time that AWS (and not the EBCLI) may spend performing the deployment, so changing this will not affect the EBCLI's behaviour in your case.

What I would also recommend is checking out [CloudWatch log streaming](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-cloudwatchlogs), using which Beanstalk can send all your logs to CloudWatch. You should be able to access them even after the environment has died, thereby letting to have some visibility into what might have gone wrong. Note that CloudWatch log streaming is a **paid service**.

Comment: trying this `eb deploy --timeout 30`

Comment: It still fails, says command execution wasn't successful. I'm starting to think there isn't a way to deploy this via elastic beanstalk

Comment: Okay, can you share the exact error message in your original post? And how about the suggestion of streaming to CloudWatch? Do you think that is feasible?